# Equivalent binary quad forms with same discriminant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

How to I show that $3x^{2} + xy + 4y^{2}$  and $3x^{2} - xy + 4y^{2}$ are not equivalent over $\mathbb{Z}$. They have the same discriminant so I can't use the contrapositive statement of equivalence $\Rightarrow$ same discriminant.

I was thinking of finding a number which one of them represent and show that the other form can't represent it, but it seems quite hard. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If we let $A(x,y)=3x^2+x y +4y^2$ and $B(x,y)=3x^2-x y +4y^2$ then $A(x,-y)=B(x,y)$ so the quadratic forms represent the same integers

Comment: @Lozenges how does that show that the two forms are not equivalent?

Comment: it doesn't. We need to think of another way to show the quadratic forms are not equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are equivalent then there exist integers $r,s,t,u$ such that 
$$B(x,y)=A(r x+ s y,t x + u y)$$
$r,s,t,u$ are the entries of a matrix $M$ in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Now, $B(1,0)=A(r,t)=3$ and $B(0,1)=A(s,u)=4$ so $r,t$ and $s,u$ must satisfy the equations
$$(6r+t)^2+47t^2=36$$
and
$$(6s+u)^2+47u^2=48$$
From the first equation $t=0$ and $r=\pm 1$.
From the second equation $u=\pm 1$ and $s=0$.
The only possibilities for the matrix $M$ are $I$ or $-I$.
Neither one of these transforms $A$ to $B$.
Therefore $A$ and $B$ are not equivalent.